# JTable with ArrayListTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, classcastexception, defaulttablemodel

I have a project with a GUI app which shows a `JTable` with data from DB. I am using `DefaultTableModel` object. My code is:

```
Facade facade = new Facade();
            ArrayList<Suppliers> suppliers = facade.getAllSuppliers();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTable Data");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(300, 600);

            Container content = frame.getContentPane();
            content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JTable table = new JTable();
            ArrayList<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
            for(int i = 0; i < suppliers.size(); i++)
            {
                list.add(new Object[]
                        {
                                suppliers.get(i).getId(),
                                suppliers.get(i).getName(),
                                suppliers.get(i).getStreet(),
                                suppliers.get(i).getCity(),
                                suppliers.get(i).getState(),
                                suppliers.get(i).getZip(),
                        });
            }
            table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(list.toArray(new Object[][]{}),
                    new String[]{"id", "name", "street", "city", "state", "zip"}));

            JScrollPane scrollList = new JScrollPane(table);
            content.add(scrollList, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    };
    EventQueue.invokeLater(runner);
```

Now, I want to create an `ArrayListTableModel` object with the functionality that offers `ArrayList` objects. Here is the code:

```
public class ArrayListTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
private ArrayList rows;

private String[] columnNames = {};

/**

 * 

 * @param columnNames

 * @param rows

 */

public ArrayListTableModel(String[] columnNames, ArrayList rows) {

    this.columnNames = columnNames;

    this.rows = rows;

}

@Override

public String getColumnName(int column) {

    if (columnNames[column] != null) {

        return columnNames[column];

    } else {

        return "";

    }

}

@Override

public int getRowCount() {

    return rows.size();

}

@Override

public int getColumnCount() {

    return columnNames.length;

}

@Override

public Object getValueAt(int aRow, int aColumn) {

    ArrayList row = (ArrayList) rows.get(aRow);

    return row.get(aColumn);

}
```

}

When I try use this class in the main method, I receive the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

I would like replace `DefaultTableModel` and use `ArrayListTableModel`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `getValueAt()` method, this line is wrong:

```
ArrayList row=(ArrayList) rows.get(aRow);
```

rows is an `ArrayList` of `Object[]` arrays, therefore, rows.get(aRow) returns `Object[]`. You will have to do something like:

```
Object[] row=(Object[])rows.get(aRow);
return row[aColumn];
```